# Limiting the .Net console buffer output area - .Net equivalent of Qbasic's VIEW PRINT statement

Tags: .net, console, qbasic

Many years ago I used to code in QBasic which had a handy statement - `VIEW PRINT` ([details here](http://www.qbasicstation.com/index.php?c=t_adv&t=65)) - and it would restrict the console output buffer to a specific clipped area in the console. Console output was displayed and would scroll previous console buffer output up just as you would expect, but within the restricted area. This made it easy to have a limited area where you could accept user input from the console, but also reserve another part of the console for displaying output that wouldn't be pushed off screen when the buffer needed to print more lines of text.

Is there any equivalent to this functionality in .Net's System.Console, and if not, are there any libraries that simulate such functionality?

Comment: That was a way, back in the DOS days, to create a simulation of a window.  We have real windows now.  One way to get this back is to temporarily replace Console.Out and put your own TextWriter in place.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547428/net-console-textwriter-that-understands-indent-unindent-indentlevel/2547800#2547800