# Is there some way to automatically indent VB.NET code in a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, indentation, code-formatting, codedom

I would like to correctly indent some VB.NET code contained within a text file. Is there some way to do this?

e.g.
Start with this:

```
Public Shared Function CanReachPage(page As String) As Boolean
Try
Using client = New WebClient()
Using stream = client.OpenRead(page)
Return True
End Using
End Using
Catch
Return False
End Try
End Function
```

finish up with this:

```
Public Shared Function CanReachPage(page As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Using client = New WebClient()
            Using stream = client.OpenRead(page)
                Return True
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Everything I have searched for has so far led me to the [IndentedTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.indentedtextwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class but the only examples I have found are to manually indent lines like this: [.NET Console TextWriter that Understands Indent/Unindent/IndentLevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547428/net-console-textwriter-that-understands-indent-unindent-indentlevel)

Extra credit: I would also like to add the correct spacing as well if possible:

e.g `Dim i As String="Hello"+"GoodBye"`  -> `Dim i As String = "Hello" + "GoodBye"`

Comment: That console example you found doesn't just work on a console.  It is a TextWriter, just like StreamWriter.  So just do it the same way, passing a TextWriter through the constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant - yes I gathered that, but it doesn't work out what the indentation should be does it? It relies on me knowing that "if the line starts with `Using` then I must indent one level" etc etc

Comment: Oh.  Yeah, writing one that understands vb.net syntax is a whole different ball game.  It used to be easy but line continuation is optional these days, that ought to give you a major migraine.

Comment: Are you copying the text from a VB project or directly writing in notepad or .txt?

Comment: @KashishArora - I am giving customers of our product the ability to write vb.net 'scripts' for which they will use notepad to edit them. I want to be able to indent this file for them.

Comment: @MattWilko: Are you looking for package this does most of this (sound like it), or do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: @IraBaxter - I was hoping there might be something built into the framework that allowed me to do this but it appears there isn't so the choices are either some home-grown code or a third party assembly to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to have a crack at rolling by own. There are some edge cases that this doesn't work 100% for, but it is pretty reliable:

```
Public Class VBIndenter

    Private _classIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _moduleIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _subIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _functionIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _propertyIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _structureIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _enumIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _usingIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _withIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _ifIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _tryIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _getIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _setIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _forIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _selectIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _doIndents As New List(Of Integer)
    Private _whileIndents As New List(Of Integer)

    Public Property IndentWidth As Integer = 4
    Public Property IndentChar As Char = " "c

    Public Sub Indent(txt As TextBox)

        Dim lastLabelIndent As Integer = 0
        Dim lastRegionIndent As Integer = 0
        Dim currentIndent As Integer = 0
        Dim inProperty As Boolean = False
        Dim lineText As String
        Dim newLineIndent As Integer
        Dim lines As String() = txt.Lines

        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1

            Dim line = lines(i)

            'get the trimmed line without any comments
            lineText = StripComments(line)

            'only change the indent on lines that are code
            If lineText.Length > 0 Then

                'special case for regions and labels - they always have zero indent
                If lineText.StartsWith("#") Then
                    lastRegionIndent = currentIndent
                    currentIndent = 0
                ElseIf lineText.EndsWith(":") Then
                    lastLabelIndent = currentIndent
                    currentIndent = 0
                End If

                'if we are in a property and we see something 
                If (_propertyIndents.Count > 0) Then
                    If Not lineText.StartsWith("End") Then
                        If lineText.StartsWith("Class ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Class ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Module ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Module ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Sub ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Sub ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Function ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Function ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Property ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Property ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Structure ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Structure ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Enum ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Enum ") Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                            currentIndent -= 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        If lineText = "End Class" Then
                            _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                If lineText = "End Class" Then
                    currentIndent = _classIndents.Item(_classIndents.Count - 1)
                    _classIndents.RemoveAt(_classIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Module" Then
                    currentIndent = _moduleIndents.Item(_moduleIndents.Count - 1)
                    _moduleIndents.RemoveAt(_moduleIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Sub" Then
                    currentIndent = _subIndents.Item(_subIndents.Count - 1)
                    _subIndents.RemoveAt(_subIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Function" Then
                    currentIndent = _functionIndents.Item(_functionIndents.Count - 1)
                    _functionIndents.RemoveAt(_functionIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Property" Then
                    currentIndent = _propertyIndents.Item(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                    _propertyIndents.RemoveAt(_propertyIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Try" Then
                    currentIndent = _tryIndents.Item(_tryIndents.Count - 1)
                    _tryIndents.RemoveAt(_tryIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End With" Then
                    currentIndent = _withIndents.Item(_withIndents.Count - 1)
                    _withIndents.RemoveAt(_withIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Get" Then
                    currentIndent = _getIndents.Item(_getIndents.Count - 1)
                    _getIndents.RemoveAt(_getIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Set" Then
                    currentIndent = _setIndents.Item(_setIndents.Count - 1)
                    _setIndents.RemoveAt(_setIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End If" Then
                    currentIndent = _ifIndents.Item(_ifIndents.Count - 1)
                    _ifIndents.RemoveAt(_ifIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Using" Then
                    currentIndent = _usingIndents.Item(_usingIndents.Count - 1)
                    _usingIndents.RemoveAt(_usingIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Structure" Then
                    currentIndent = _structureIndents.Item(_structureIndents.Count - 1)
                    _structureIndents.RemoveAt(_structureIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Select" Then
                    currentIndent = _selectIndents.Item(_selectIndents.Count - 1)
                    _selectIndents.RemoveAt(_selectIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End Enum" Then
                    currentIndent = _enumIndents.Item(_enumIndents.Count - 1)
                    _enumIndents.RemoveAt(_enumIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "End While" OrElse lineText = "Wend" Then
                    currentIndent = _whileIndents.Item(_whileIndents.Count - 1)
                    _whileIndents.RemoveAt(_whileIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "Next" OrElse lineText.StartsWith("Next ") Then
                    currentIndent = _forIndents.Item(_forIndents.Count - 1)
                    _forIndents.RemoveAt(_forIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText = "Loop" OrElse lineText.StartsWith("Loop ") Then
                    currentIndent = _doIndents.Item(_doIndents.Count - 1)
                    _doIndents.RemoveAt(_doIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Else") Then
                    currentIndent = _ifIndents.Item(_ifIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Catch") Then
                    currentIndent = _tryIndents.Item(_tryIndents.Count - 1)
                ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Case") Then
                    currentIndent = _selectIndents.Item(_selectIndents.Count - 1) + 1
                ElseIf lineText = "Finally" Then
                    currentIndent = _tryIndents.Item(_tryIndents.Count - 1)
                End If

            End If

            'find the current indent
            newLineIndent = currentIndent * Me.IndentWidth
            'change the indent of the current line 
            line = New String(IndentChar, newLineIndent) & line.TrimStart
            lines(i) = line

            If lineText.Length > 0 Then
                If lineText.StartsWith("#") Then
                    currentIndent = lastRegionIndent
                ElseIf lineText.EndsWith(":") Then
                    currentIndent = lastLabelIndent
                End If

                If Not lineText.StartsWith("End") Then
                    If (lineText.StartsWith("Class ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Class ")) Then
                        _classIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf (lineText.StartsWith("Module ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Module ")) Then
                        _moduleIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf (lineText.StartsWith("Sub ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Sub ")) Then
                        _subIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf (lineText.StartsWith("Function ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Function ")) Then
                        _functionIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf (lineText.StartsWith("Property ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Property ")) Then
                        _propertyIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf (lineText.StartsWith("Structure ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Structure ")) Then
                        _structureIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf (lineText.StartsWith("Enum ") OrElse lineText.Contains(" Enum ")) Then
                        _enumIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.Contains("Using ") Then
                        _usingIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Select Case") Then
                        _selectIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText = "Try" Then
                        _tryIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText = "Get" Then
                        _getIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Set") AndAlso Not lineText.Contains("=") Then
                        _setIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("With") Then
                        _withIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("If") AndAlso lineText.EndsWith("Then") Then
                        _ifIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("For") Then
                        _forIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("While") Then
                        _whileIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Do") Then
                        _doIndents.Add(currentIndent)
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Case") Then
                        currentIndent += 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Else") Then
                        currentIndent = _ifIndents.Item(_ifIndents.Count - 1) + 1
                    ElseIf lineText.StartsWith("Catch") Then
                        currentIndent = _tryIndents.Item(_tryIndents.Count - 1) + 1
                    ElseIf lineText = "Finally" Then
                        currentIndent = _tryIndents.Item(_tryIndents.Count - 1) + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'update the textbox
        txt.Lines = lines
    End Sub

    Private Function StripComments(ByVal code As String) As String
        If code.IndexOf("'"c) >= 0 Then
            code = code.Substring(0, code.IndexOf("'"c))
        End If
        Return code.Trim
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

Put some code into a TextBox (`TextBox1`), then call the indenter like this:

```
Dim id As New VBIndenter
id.Indent(TextBox1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Visual Studio (I'm looking at VS 2010 at the moment; I don't know offhand what earlier versions did) then you can go to the Edit->Advanced->Format Document and it should take care of the indentation and spacing for you.

Note that this works for any type of document that Visual Studio understands. I regularly use this trick to format XML documents into something legible.

Comment: Thanks but I want to do this on a machine that doesn't have VS installed

Comment: Formatting VB code without using an IDE is a rather significant restriction. As @HansPassant mentioned above, writing your own VB parser is going to be a non-trivial undertaking. You didn't really mention why you're trying to do this, but it's at least worth considering whether installing the [free](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs), entry-level version of Visual Studio on the computer in question might be worthwhile, if only to use to format your files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with using pre-release software, you could use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx):

```
Dim parsed = Syntax.ParseCompilationUnit(text)
Dim normalized = parsed.NormalizeWhitespace()
Console.WriteLine(normalized)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. This works for **C Syntax.** Slightly modify it to use it with a
   file. This one provides **real-time indent while typing**.
2. Concept is same just modify it with (whenever it finds a **chr(13)**
   or newline character) of file instead of (e.keycode=13) and your (**current index I** of file reader) instead of TextBox1.SelectionStart.
3. Make slight changes that would suit your file needs. I am not re-writing
   as anyone looking to make IDE would find this handy. **Use code
   converter for the C# code.**

---

Here's the little code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp    
If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
   Dim k = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.SelectionStart)
   Dim a = k.Split("{").Length - 1, b = k.Split("}").Length - 1
   If (a - b) > -1 Then SendKeys.Send(New String(" ", (a - b) * 2))
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

One way to do this is to build a parser and a prettyprinter.
The parser reads the source and builds an AST capturing the essence of
the program structure.  The prettyprinter takes the tree,
and regenerates output based on the structure; thus it is "easy"
to get structured output.  As a key hint, for each level of
language structure (classes, methods, blocks, loops, conditionals),
the prettyprinter can indent the prettyprinted text to give
good indentation structure.

Parsing and prettyprinting are both pretty complicated topics.
Rather than repeat all that here, you can see
 my [SO answer on how to parse, with follow on discussion on how to build an AST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163).   Prettyprinting is not so well known,
but [this SO answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832412/compiling-an-ast-back-to-source-code/5834775#5834775) provides a pretty complete description
of how to do it.

Then you have the complication of determining the actual grammar of VB.net.  That requires a lot of work to extract from the reference documentation... and it isn't quite right,  so you need to validate your parser against a lot of code to convince yourself it right.  This part is unfortunately just sweat.

Given a prettyprinter program, OP can simply launch it as a process to format a file.

If you do all that, then yes you can format VB.net text. Our (standalone) VB.net formatter  ("DMSFormat ...") does the above to achieve prettyprinting.

Given the file "vb_example.net":

```
Module Test
Public Shared Function CanReachPage(page As String) As Boolean
Try
Using client = New WebClient()
Using stream = client.OpenRead(page)
Return True
End Using
End Using
Catch
Return False
End Try
End Function
End Module
```

The following:

```
C:>DMSFormat VisualBasic~VBdotNet  C:\temp\vb_example.net
```

produces:

```
VisualBasic~VBdotNet Formatter/Obfuscator Version 1.2.1
Copyright (C) 2010 Semantic Designs, Inc
Powered by DMS (R) Software Reengineering Toolkit
Parsing C:\temp\vb_example.net [encoding ISO-8859-1]


Module Test
  Public Shared Function CanReachPage(page As String) As Boolean
    Try
      Using client = New WebClient()
        Using stream = client.OpenRead(page)
          Return True
        End Using
      End Using
    Catch
      Return False
    End Try
  End Function
End Module
```

which is identical to what OP wanted in his example.

You can easily direct the formatted program content to a file.

You can give the tool a project file, and it will format as many files as you specify
in the project file at once.

The formatter integrates a complete VB.net parser,
 and our own prettyprinting machinery.  It parses
the source text precisely (including strange character
encodings).  Because it uses a reliable parser and prettyprinter, it will not break the code.

The eval version works on files of a few hundred lines of code.  It might be just what you need.

I'd provide a link but SO seems to dislike that.  You can find this through my bio.

Comment: That great and all, but you didn't provide a link to where this tool is, who mention who the "our" is.

Comment: That's because SO policy objects and I take enormous flak when I post links to "our" tools.  "Our" means just that; check my bio.  If you think these restrictions are wrong, take it up in Meta.

Comment: Without that information, this answer is utterly useless. I'm not the one who should be taking up on meta. You should be. In fact, you'll find that such answers [are perfectly acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/256822), because it *directly relates* to the question.

Comment: Just what I like about SO.  I provide a production, working answer.  It gets downvoted.